# how can I access control of different pages in UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a horizontal UIScrollView. It have 3 pages. It I have 3 UIButtons on each page of the scrollview. Total of 9 UIButtons. I need to set a different color when a button is touched, so that I can differentiate that touched button with the other buttons.

I tried setColor by checking BOOL values. It is working for single page. 
When I touch a button it's color is changed and I can remove the color for other buttons in same page. But, the color set in other page is still there.

How can I set the other button colors (of other pages) to nil when I touch on any button in any page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep references to the *UIButton* objects that are being added as subviews of the other *UIScrollView* pages.  If you have references to all nine button objects from the view controller (containing the *UIScrollView*) then you will be able to arbitrarily set their state from the touch handlers for the nine buttons.

Comment: I am keeping he references of all the nine buttons. I am able to call different methods for all the nine buttons. In that method I am setting the values(colors) of the  buttons. But, I could not get the solution.

Comment: @srikanth-rongali Are you trying to set the background color on a UIButtonTypeRoundedRect type button? Unfortunately that won't work.  Check out this post for details on setting button background colors: http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/

Comment: @@srikanth-rongali If there is anything I can add here. Let me know.